# Merging multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes with varying column numbers and many thousands of rows. Every DF has Year and ISO columns. I want to merge all of them into a final DF that has a single Year and ISO columns and unique value column/s that correspond to those from the original DFs. The final output has to go back out in .xlsx format so I'd like to minimize the number of rows which are populated with mostly NA.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ISOcodes)

df1 = data.frame(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value1 = sample(1:100, 10))
df2 = data.frame(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value2 = sample(1:100, 10))
df3 = data.frame(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value3 = sample(1:100, 10))
df4 = data.frame(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value4 = sample(1:100, 10))
df5 = data.frame(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value5 = sample(1:100, 10))

full_df = merge(df1, df2, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
full_df = merge(full_df, df3, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
full_df = merge(full_df, df4, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
full_df = merge(full_df, df5, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
```

I have to specify `all = T` so that I don't lose data. This solution feels very clunky and I'm sure there must be more elegant ways to do it (possibly with `data.table`?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Note - you can test the minimizing of `NA` by forcing df5 to have the same Year and ISO values as df4. Then you would expect the final output to have a `dim()` of ~ 40x7 rather than 50x7 (depending on sample).

```
df5$Year <- df4$Year
df5$ISO  <- df4$ISO
```

Nested `dplyr::full_join()` will minimize the `NA`

```
library(dplyr)
test_join <- full_join(df1, full_join(df2, full_join(df3, full_join(df4, df5))))
```

Not minimizing `NA` - `dplyr::bind_rows()` "Efficiently bind multiple data frames by row".

```
library(dplyr)
test_df <- bind_rows(df1, df2,df3,df4,df5)
```

Clunky, but will minimize `NA` - `data.table::merge()` a method for "Fast merge of two data.tables".

```
library(data.table)
dt1 = data.table(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value1 = sample(1:100, 10))
dt2 = data.table(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value2 = sample(1:100, 10))
dt3 = data.table(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value3 = sample(1:100, 10))
dt4 = data.table(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value4 = sample(1:100, 10))
dt5 = data.table(Year = sample(2000:2020, 10),
                 ISO = sample(ISO_3166_1$Alpha_2, 10),
                 value5 = sample(1:100, 10))

full_dt = merge(dt1, dt2, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
full_dt = merge(full_dt, dt3, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
full_dt = merge(full_dt, dt4, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
full_dt = merge(full_dt, dt5, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
mylist <- mget(paste0('df',1:5))
Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x,y, all= TRUE), mylist)
   Year ISO value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
1  2000  PK     NA     NA     NA     56     NA
2  2000  SX     28     NA     NA     NA     NA
3  2001  AZ     NA     NA     NA     45     NA
4  2001  BY     NA     NA     NA     NA     93
5  2001  GQ     NA     68     NA     NA     NA
6  2001  KW     NA     NA      8     NA     NA
7  2002  AL     17     NA     NA     NA     NA
8  2002  LV     NA     93     NA     NA     NA
9  2002  TK     NA     NA     NA     NA     60
10 2003  MP     12     NA     NA     NA     NA
11 2003  NC     NA     NA     NA     68     NA
12 2004  AF     90     NA     NA     NA     NA
13 2004  AQ     NA     31     NA     NA     NA
14 2004  PG     NA     NA     NA     NA     45
15 2005  BH     NA     34     NA     NA     NA
16 2005  DZ     NA     NA     NA     NA     83
17 2006  PS     NA     NA     NA     98     NA
18 2006  TK     98     NA     NA     NA     NA
19 2006  TL     NA     NA     16     NA     NA
20 2007  HT     33     NA     NA     NA     NA
21 2007  PN     NA     NA     NA     NA     70
22 2007  VE     NA     60     NA     NA     NA
23 2008  BO     NA     NA     NA     52     NA
24 2008  TW     NA     NA     NA     NA     64
25 2009  LR     30     NA     NA     NA     NA
26 2009  MH     NA     NA     NA     60     NA
27 2009  TR     NA     NA     15     NA     NA
28 2010  FO     NA     12     NA     NA     NA
29 2010  LY     NA     NA     NA     11     NA
30 2010  ML     89     NA     NA     NA     NA
31 2011  GW     NA     NA     40     NA     NA
32 2012  BY     NA     NA     83     NA     NA
33 2012  HK     NA     NA     NA     NA     68
34 2012  PM     NA     NA     NA     72     NA
35 2014  ET     NA     NA     NA     NA     24
36 2014  MP     NA     NA     64     NA     NA
37 2014  WS     NA     20     NA     NA     NA
38 2016  GT     NA     NA     NA     NA     51
39 2016  JM     NA     97     NA     NA     NA
40 2016  UY     42     NA     NA     NA     NA
41 2017  CK     NA     NA     NA     64     NA
42 2017  WF     NA     NA     76     NA     NA
43 2018  FK     NA     NA     NA     97     NA
44 2018  PK     NA     NA     26     NA     NA
45 2019  AM     NA     41     NA     NA     NA
46 2019  CZ     75     NA     NA     NA     NA
47 2019  LS     NA     NA     NA     NA     46
48 2019  TV     NA     NA     10     NA     NA
49 2020  FM     NA     NA     79     NA     NA
50 2020  MR     NA     65     NA     NA     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)
purrr::reduce(.x = l, merge, by = c('Year', 'ISO'), all = T)

   Year ISO value1 value2 value3 value4 value5
1  2000  KZ     NA     75     NA     NA     NA
2  2000  TF     NA     NA     NA     NA     34
3  2001  AD     NA     NA     NA     NA     31
4  2001  ML     NA     NA     87     NA     NA
5  2001  NF      8     NA     NA     NA     NA
6  2002  CC     NA     NA     NA     12     NA
7  2002  NF     NA     63     NA     NA     NA
8  2002  SD     42     NA     NA     NA     NA
9  2002  SY     NA     NA     NA     NA     45
10 2003  AW     NA     NA     41     NA     NA
11 2003  BR     NA     NA     NA     42     NA
12 2003  TT     96     NA     NA     NA     NA
13 2004  KE     NA    100     NA     NA     NA
14 2005  CG     NA     NA     NA     NA     67
15 2006  BV     NA     NA     67     NA     NA
16 2006  BW     NA      9     NA     NA     NA
17 2006  GU     18     NA     NA     NA     NA
18 2007  CG     NA     NA     NA     81     NA
19 2007  IM     NA     18     NA     NA     NA
20 2008  BH     NA     NA    100     NA     NA
21 2008  MD     28     NA     NA     NA     NA
22 2008  PY     NA     NA     NA     NA     96
23 2008  TR     NA     NA     NA     87     NA
24 2009  SM     NA     NA     NA     53     NA
25 2010  GF     NA     NA     56     NA     NA
26 2010  LU     NA     NA     NA     43     NA
27 2010  PM     NA     80     NA     NA     NA
28 2011  MF     NA     NA     38     NA     NA
29 2012  CF     NA     56     NA     NA     NA
30 2012  JO     NA     NA     NA     16     NA
31 2012  UG     NA     NA     63     NA     NA
32 2013  BY     68     NA     NA     NA     NA
33 2013  MT     NA     13     NA     NA     NA
34 2013  NO     NA     NA     NA     74     NA
35 2014  TR     NA     NA     NA     NA     98
36 2015  GM     NA     NA     NA     NA     27
37 2015  SC     71     NA     NA     NA     NA
38 2016  MM     NA     NA     65     NA     NA
39 2017  AX     50     NA     NA     NA     NA
40 2017  BA     NA     NA      8     NA     NA
41 2017  MF     NA     NA     NA     NA     20
42 2017  SH     NA     NA     NA      6     NA
43 2018  GU     NA     46     NA     NA     NA
44 2018  LR     NA     NA     NA     NA     56
45 2018  MK     33     NA     NA     NA     NA
46 2018  SN     NA     NA     82     NA     NA
47 2019  NA     26     NA     NA     NA     NA
48 2019  TW     NA     NA     NA     51     NA
49 2020  AQ     NA     28     NA     NA     NA
50 2020  FO     NA     NA     NA     NA     81
```