# Automatically recode variable values based on possible order of occurrence in R

Tags: r, merge, recode

I am working on processing data from multiple surveys in R. These surveys contain the same questions completed in different languages. For some of the questions, selections that indicate the same response have unfortunately been saved under a different value, and I want to recode these so that they are the same across surveys.

For instance, participants have to select the country that they live in (out of 195 options). In the English version this looks like this:

| Country selected in the survey | Stored as value in the dataset |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 1 |
| Albania | 2 |
| Algeria | 3 |
| […] | [...] |
| Zimbabwe | 195 |

In the Italian version, the same variable looks like this:

| Country selected in the survey | Stored as value in the dataset |
| --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2 |
| Albania | 198 |
| Algeria | 199 |
| […] | [...] |
| Zimbabwe | 391 |

In other words, the order of the countries/values is the same, but the saved values don’t match between English + Italian.

I can manually recode each value (i.e., in the Italian version recode 2 as 1, 198 as 2, 199 as 3, etc.) but it takes a lot of time to go through 195 options for multiple surveys.
Is there some way that I can automate this, so that the smallest possible value in the Italian version (in this example, value 2) gets recoded to 1, and the largest possible value (in this example, value 391) gets recoded to 195, and everything in between gets recoded accordingly automatically as well?

(Please note this is about recoding the *possible* values, as the dataset does not necessarily contain a value from each response option.)

Thank you!

Comment: Are both country (character) and country code (integer) present in the data frames/files?

Comment: Yes, in each language version the variable contains a label (if that is how it's called, sorry am new to R). This label shows each country (albeit in the language of the survey, e.g. 'Stati Uniti d’America' for the USA in the Italian version) and its corresponding code. In the label, the countries are listed in the same order regardless of the language of the survey.

Comment: Translate the country names so they are all in the same language, then it becomes a 'merge by country names' job: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68287677/14027775

Comment: You could call it a label, but it is just another column (variable) in your data frame, correct? I think you will have to translate the names as marcguery suggested. This could be done automatically if you create a data frame of country names with a different language in each column. Then you could merge, or, if you don't want to do that, you could always make a consistent integer code with <- as.integer(factor(dfeng$country, levels = sort(unique(c(dfeng$country, dfit$country, . . .)))). That will give you the same factor levels (and order) in all data frames (just shown for one there).

Comment: In the end I found out that the numerical discrepancy between English & non-English country codes was consistent between all versions. So I recalculated the non-English codes to match the English language version. And then I re-applied the English-language labels to the country codes. So I did it the other way around but your suggestions would have worked as well (and probably a bit cleaner to do it that way). Thank you for your help.